# What's the best way to end a loop inside a coroutine function after time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

This is my very first question, everything is clear I guess -

Loop in a coroutine (UnityC#) is not behaving correctly, or what am I doing wrong! check the code comments...

```cs
bool loop=true;
bool once=false;   

IEnumerator Fun()
{
    while (loop)
    {
        //those 3 lines must be repeated for the whole 2.5 seconds,am I right! but it only run once so why?
        carRb.drag += .005f;
        Debug.Log("Loop1:"+loop);
        if (!once)          //last rep. line
        { 
            once = true;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.5f); 
            loop = false;
        }
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f); //will run this line after 2.5s        
    Debug.Log("Loop2: "+loop);      //will run this line and whats below after (2.5+2s) 
    carRb.drag = 25f;
    carController.canControl = false;
    Destroyed = true; 
}
```

Comment: How can we tell you what you're doing wrong when you've not told us what you're trying to do?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] clearly demonstrating the issue you're having

Comment: am trying to end the loop in the courotine after 2.5 seconds , it ends after 1 frame only

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please excuse the trolls here, there seems to be a culture lately of jumping on people who ask reasonable questions but don't 100% follow the rules. To end the loop after a certain time you just need a timer variable inside the loop and add 2.5 seconds to it. When it gets to your threshold value the loop should exit. Change `While (loop)` to `While (myTimer < 30)` or whatever time you choose. The above comment is right though, the format for questions is: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The **clearest way** to explain the misunderstanding here is :

1. WaitForSeconds is not working in a sperate box or something-like that
   so
2. It stops the whole code from continuing until time ends and that means even if we wait before closing the loop(setting loop=false) we will still be in the first iteration.
   and the best way to end the loop is by using a numerical variable , increase it every frame and check if it reaches the time we want then break

### *Thanks to @user3315036 & @Absinthe*

> Code will be like:

```
IEnumerator Fun(){
    float time=0;

    while(time<2.5f){
        carRb.drag += .005f;
        Debug.Log("Loop1");
        time+=Time.deltaTime;       
        yield return null;

    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f); //will run this line after 2.5s        
    Debug.Log("2: ");      //will run this line and whats below after (2.5+2s) 
    carRb.drag = 25f;
    carController.canControl = false;
    Destroyed = true; 

}
```

Comment: When someone is able to your question in the comments, it's customary to ask them to add an answer and accept it.

Comment: their answers were not the good answers 1st , 
this was the answer: (value of once is false, so its entering if condition then waiting for 2.5s and ending the loop) 
and they edited them after discussion , and even after edits they we're not clear , I mention their names in BIG BOLD Title

Answer (score 2):

value of once is false, so its entering if condition then waiting for 2.5s and ending the loop.

```
bool loop=true;
bool once=false;

IEnumerator Fun()
{
    float time=0;
    while (loop)
    {
        //those 3 lines must be repeated for the whole 2.5 seconds,am I right! but it only run once so why?
        carRb.drag += .005f;
        Debug.Log("Loop1:"+loop);
        yield return null;  // wait each update call
        time+=Time.deltaTime;
        if (time>2.5f)          //last rep. line
        {
            once = true;
            loop = false;
        }
    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f); //will run this line after 2.5s
    Debug.Log("Loop2: "+loop);      //will run this line and whats below after (2.5+2s)
    carRb.drag = 25f;
    carController.canControl = false;
    Destroyed = true;
}
```

Comment: thats what I was trying to do when I wrote the code , but unfortunately its not working like that ,
its just running once (1frame) and the Log function printed one time only

Comment: You didn't give anything new , thank you anyway

Comment: you are closing the loop in first iteration, so its not going to loop more than once. wait for seconds make the code wait 2.5s. it does not execute next line of code before that time

Comment: yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.5f);  the code just sit there and do nothing. after 2.5 sencode loop = false; line execute. so in next iteration while loop exit

Comment: and how the next line after it which is loop=false; is happening , ... ur saying it does nothing but its not preventing whats after it to excute , could u explain really thanks

Comment: i think you missundersting what WaitForSeconds(2.5). it waits in that line for the 2.5s. after 2.5s passes it moved to next line and set loop=false. then WaitForEndOfFrame() is executed and waits until next frame. then in next iteration loop=false and loop ends

Comment: ok u edited ur comment , its clear now ... maybe ur saying that it does wait for 2.5s and its not like it does nothing literally but it also preventing the compiler from continuing the loop until it waits, so even if loop=false is happening after 2.5 the whole code stopes whenever there is a wait . that make sense now thanks

Comment: yes i was misunderstanding the Wait , so I can now say it does wait for 2.5 s but its still in first iteration even after waiting,i was thinking it does its work in like-another thread or something seperate , thank you